# Issues playing audio in a Raphael JS animation

Tags: javascript, html, audio, onclick, raphael

I have a Raphael JS animation which works fine, but I am trying to get an audio track to start playing when a node is clicked, essentially

```
var track = new Audio("test.mp3");

ufo_body.node.onclick = function(){
    track.play();
    ...
```

There are other functions called by the onclick function after the track.play();, but they all work fine so it does accept the track.play() but I cannot hear it. Other sounds are playing fine on other parts of the website containing the animation.

All of the animation javascript is within a `window.onload= function (){` environment, if that's a factor. My supervisor (this is a university project) can't see what's missing from it either. Any suggestions for workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for playing audio

```
  <html>
  <head>
      <title>Sound Test</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="raphael.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="debugPane" style="width: 300px; height: 500px; float: left; background-color: #EEEEEE; margin-left: 10px; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          try {
              var snd = new Audio("mp3/1.mp3");
              alert(snd.src);
              snd.play();
          } catch (err) {
              document.getElementById("debugPane").innerHTML += "" + err.message;
          }
      </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```